# Linux alternative to Windows Script Host

Tags: scripts

I've just switched from Windows to Ubuntu. Really enjoying it right now and haven't encountered any issues whatsoever. The only thing is that I'm really gonna miss a lot of useful things that Windows has.

That being said, I don't even know that Ubuntu doesn't have their own alternatives.

On Windows, you've got the Windows Script Host (WSH). You can use JScript or VBScript for example, to create scripts that perform a variety of tasks. You can save these scripts as .js or .vbs or .wsh files and double-click these files to execute their code.

Does Linux/Ubuntu have an alternative to the Windows Script Host?

Answer (score 1):

basicly BASH scripts provides all you would need with full fledged loops and conditions, variables and system calls, so that you can affect all the aspects of the system and automate tasks, and i think GNU/Linux in general is the master,in this kind of stuff, so VBS or JS, you have it in the form of Shell scripts, like i mentioned BASH is the famous amongs almost all the distributions, but it is not the only one out there, CSH, SH (bourne shell) KSH,TcSH and many many more.
good luck

Comment: You could've described it in more detail. But it's short & sweet intro to this topic.

Comment: @jay_t55 You will find many tutorial sites where you can learn about this SHELL & how to Write scripts, You have chosen an Open Source OS, it's very large platform itself dude, no limits are there like back at WINDOWS. You just need to start over on this. Best of Luck.